# Not able to read array length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an external file, wherein I am declaring my global variable to be imported.

**BOQSuggestions.js**

```
var BOQSuggestions = []

export default BOQSuggestions;
```

I am importing the global variable in my **TasksInsert.jsx** like this :

```
import BOQSuggestions from './BOQSuggestions';
```

In the `return` part of my `render()` function, I have the following code :

```
return (
      <Wrapper>
      <Title>Insert a Task</Title>
       <Label>Description: </Label>
       <InputText
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search for tasks in the BOQ..."
          value={ taskName }
          onChange={this.handleChangeInputTaskName}
        />
       <h1>{BOQSuggestions.length}</h1>
       ...
```

My **handleChangeInputTaskName** function is as follows :

```
handleChangeInputTaskName = async event => {
   var taskName = event.target.value

   if(taskName.charAt(taskName.length -1) == ' '){
      api.autoCompleteBOQ(taskName).then(res => {
        var autoresultArray = res.data.data.hits.hits
        var autoResult = []

        for(var i = 0; i < autoresultArray.length; i++){
          autoResult = (JSON.stringify(autoresultArray[i]._source.boqList))             
         BOQSuggestions.push(JSON.stringify(autoresultArray[i]._source.boqList))
       }

      console.log('Length of the suggestions array ====> ', BOQSuggestions.length )

      }).catch(error => {        
      console.log('Some error got while performing autocomplete ')
      })      
     }
      this.setState({taskName})    
   }
```

I am getting the correct value of `BOQSuggestions.length` in the `handleChangeInputTaskName` function, however in the return function, the value of the length always remains zero.

Is there anyway I can maintain the state of this variable, since it has been imported as a global variable? I do not want to use Redux or any other library for this purpose since this is the only place I need the state to be consistent.

I am relatively new to both React and Javascript. Please help me out here. Thank you!

Comment: How does your state constructor looks?

Comment: constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = 
        {
            projectId: this.props.match.params.id,
            BOQSuggestions : [],

    }

    }

Comment: Without any state keeping system, react does not know when it should update the page.

Comment: I did this but it's still not reflecting the value correctly : this.state = { suggestions : BOQSuggestions, } @Ferrybig

Answer (score 1):

Hi i think that in your method **handleChangeInputName** you are mutating the data inside your **BOQSuggestions.js** , why instead of this you dont change the state of your app? Maybe try something like this:

If you are initializing your state as with the imported value of **BOQSuggestions**:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = { 
    projectId: this.props.match.params.id, 
    BOQSuggestions : BOQSuggestions , 
 } };
```

in your **handleChangeInputName** you should update the prop in this way:

```
handleChangeInputTaskName = async event => {
   var taskName = event.target.value
   var tempBOQ = this.state.tempBOQ;

   if(taskName.charAt(taskName.length -1) == ' '){
      api.autoCompleteBOQ(taskName).then(res => {
        var autoresultArray = res.data.data.hits.hits
        var autoResult = []

        for(var i = 0; i < autoresultArray.length; i++){
          autoResult = (JSON.stringify(autoresultArray[i]._source.boqList)) 
          // Here instead of mutating BOQSuggestion imported value
          // You should modify the state property of BOQSuggestion
          tempBOQ = [...tempBOQ, JSON.stringify(autoresultArray[i]._source.boqList)]
       }
      // So here you should check the length of the tempBOQ instead of the BOQSuggestions
      console.log('Length of the suggestions array ====> ', tempBOQ.length )

      }).catch(error => {        
      console.log('Some error got while performing autocomplete ')
      })      
     }
      // And here in the setState Method you should update the BOQSugegstions
      // Anbd maybe just to confirma that everything updated correctly use the callback of the setState To check when the data was already updated
      this.setState({taskName, BOQSuggestions: tempBOQ}, () => {  console.log(this.state.BOQSuggestions)})    
   }
```

Just remember that the `setState` method is **async** so if you check it just after calling it, the value probably will not be updated .

And now every tme that you want to use your **BOQSuggestions** you should access it as : `this.state.BOQSuggestions`

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Ricardo I got the code working by modifying my method as follows :

```
handleChangeInputTaskName = async event => {
        var taskName = event.target.value

        //Triggers the autocomplete when the user hits the space bar
        if ( taskName.charAt(taskName.length -1) == ' ')
        {

            api.autoCompleteBOQ(taskName).then(res => {
            var autoresultArray = res.data.data.hits.hits
            var autoResult = []

            for(var i = 0; i < autoresultArray.length; i++)
            {
                autoResult = (JSON.stringify(autoresultArray[i]._source.boqList))

                BOQSuggestions.push(autoresultArray[i]._source.boqList)
            }

                console.log('Length of the suggestions array ====> ', BOQSuggestions.length )
                this.setState({ BOQSuggestions })


            }).catch(error => {

                console.log('Some error got while performing autocomplete ')
            })

        }

    }
```

The length gets reflected correctly in the render().

@Ricardo Gonzalez, thank you so much for your prompt response! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Great ! if your question got solved feel free to accept the answer that worked for you!